# How to send Post request for each iteration of an array in Node/Express?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I have some raw json that I'm trying to send to my back end server in mysql. I'm currently trying to loop through the specific array in the json that I need and sending data from each of the children in the array via a POST request but I am getting "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client".

```
app.post('/reddit-import', function (req, res) {
     console.log("Route /reddit-import POST");
     let data = req.body.data.children

     data.forEach(child => {

         let sql1 = `CALL insert_user('${child.data.author}', 
              '${child.data.author_fullname}');`
         connection.query(sql1, 
            data, 
            function (errQuery, result) {
               if (errQuery) {
                  console.log(errQuery);
                  res.json({status: "Error", err: errQuery});
                  res.end();
               } else {
                  console.log("Insert ID: ", result.insertId);
                  res.json({status: result.insertId, err: ""});
                  res.end();
               }
            }
         );
```

When I send the POST request, my backend gets 2 rows of data before it hits me with the error message...any ideas?

Comment: You're sending responses in each loop iteration (`res.json()` and`res.end()`), which means you're trying to send response multiple times in a single request. This is why you're getting the set headers error.

Comment: When should I be sending the response?

Comment: You should be sending the response at the very end, more specifically, after you finished processing the data. That being said, you have two options to achieve that easily: Fix your SQL in such a way that you insert everything in one go, or use map instead of forEach and use Promises to keep track of your insert IDs if you need.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be ending your outer response in the data.forEach with a res.end(), which I’m assuming is used to indicate the end of the outer HTTP request to the client. Did you perhaps mean to use “result” there instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you need to keep track insert IDs:

```
app.post('/reddit-import', function(req, res) {
  console.log("Route /reddit-import POST");
  let data = req.body.data.children

  const insertIds = data.map(child => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const sql = `CALL insert_user('${child.data.author}', '${child.data.author_fullname}')`;

      connection.query(sql, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          return reject(err);
        }

        console.log("Insert ID: ", result.insertId);
        return resolve(result.insertId);
      });
    });
  });

  return Promise.all(insertIds)
    .then(ids => {
      return res.json({
        insertIds: ids
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      return res.status(500).json({
        message: 'got query error'
      });
    });
});
```

What this basically does is that on each query, you keep track of the insert IDs. We need to use `Promise`s because the `query()` function is asynchronous, meaning it runs independently and there's no other way to keep track of the data outside of its `function(err, result)` callback. Now we have an array of `Promise`s which contains the insert IDs, and what's left is to send a response that this is successful. And in order to do that, we can't simply do `res.json(insertIds)` because `insertIds` is an array of `Promise`s and we still need to extract the values. We can easily extract all data at once from an array of `Promise`s by using `Promise.all(insertIds).then(ids => ...)`. If you wish to send a response informing that the request is successful, do so in this `then` callback. Lastly and most importantly, we handle errors in a Promise chain's `.catch()` block. This is where you want to send a response informing the client that there are errors.

Some things that we can improve from this solution is to implement rollbacks in case we have errors, and of course validations of parameters. Unfortunately I have to leave this to the OP to implement.

Also, keep in mind you should only send a response once and only once each request.